# undeletable 0 byte file

Tags: windows, file

I have a file in Wnidows/System32 that has a size of 0 bytes.
It's shown there in explorer and command prompt, bu I can't delete nor overwrite it. the system claims the file would not exist, but it stays there even after reboot.

The problem causes the installation of an app to fail because the installation also fails to overwrite the file.

I tried to delete via console, 
I tried checkdisk, fileassassin, unlocker etc. all failed to delete the file.

I would be glad if anyone could help?

The system is a virtual Windows 2008 R2 server

```
c:\Windows\System32>dir /x msvcp*


Volume in drive C has no label.
Volume Serial Number is ECD7-BEFA

Directory of c:\Windows\System32

13.08.2014  15:17                 0              msvcp100.dll
05.11.2012  23:26           661.456              msvcp110.dll
11.09.2013  19:39           614.000 MSVCP1~1.DLL msvcp110_clr0400.dll
14.07.2009  03:41           597.504              msvcp60.dll
               4 File(s)      1.872.960 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  93.173.768.192 bytes free



c:\Windows\System32>del /F msvcp100.dll
c:\Windows\System32\msvcp100.dll
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: have you tried running checkdisk?

Comment: have you tried Safe Mode? :D

Comment: have you tried running checkdisk?
Yes I did, however since I can only access the server via remote desktop, and since it is a virtual server, I'am not entirely sure that this worked as expected. I was only able to schedule a scan for reboot. Any Idea how to make sure it runs checkdisk?

Comment: Can you see the permissions of the file? Is there any synchronization set up?